# #Angular7 [ngStyle] background-image not working in Angular 7 Material

Tags: angular-material, angular7

I have a app.component.html and some images in .assets/images/

But browser annouce that ERROR TypeError: _co.url is not a function
Could you help me fix thí issue. Thanks

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container" autosize>
  <mat-sidenav #sidenav class="mat-elevation-z4" mode="side">
    <mat-nav-list *ngFor="let source of mSources">
        <div mat-card-avatar [ngStyle]="{'background': url('../assets/images/abc-news.png')}" ></div>
      <mat-list-item>{{source.name}}</mat-list-item>
    </mat-nav-list>
  </mat-sidenav>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your formatting of the ngStyle value is incorrect. The value needs to be a string - as you have it, it is a function named 'url' because [ngStyle] will try to evaluate it as an expression. It should be:

```
[ngStyle]="{'background': 'url(\'../assets/images/abc-news.png\')'}"
```

But - since you aren't using an expression, you don't need [ngStyle] you can just use style:

```
style="background: url('../assets/images/abc-news.png');"
```